# How to know if a handle has been already initialized

Tags: c, libuv

The handles in `libuv` must be initialized before the use.
All of them have an associated `uv_<handle>_init` function. As an example, `uv_timer_t` has an associated function `uv_timer_init` to initialize it.

That said, I noticed that `libuv` has an undefined behavior if I call more than once the init function for a given handle.
It shows problems once I close the loop and performs a bunch of invalid read/write operations.
Is there a way to know wheter a handle has been already initialized?

As an example, to know if a handle *is closing or closed* there exists the function `uv_is_closing`.
Is there a similar function to know if a handle is already initialized?

Comment: You could use a datastructure to track initialized variables if they are of the same type you could define your own hash function and perform a look-up. Alternatively you could store variable names in such a structure, but that is not something I'd recommend as renaming variables becomes a chore.

Comment: The fact that you encounter undefined behavior when calling the init function more than once, definitely hints to the assumption that the answer is "you cannot" - Otherwise the library would be able to detect it itself...

Comment: @tofro I don't think so. An example is the `uv_close` function. You should not call it twice and you have the `uv_is_closing` function to check if it's already closed.

Comment: A handle is like a pay-check.  Just a piece of paper with a number on it, when you take it to the bank to cash it then lots of machines are whirring in the background.  Taking it to the bank twice or never at all, well, you can imagine.  Programming is all about making sane decisions.

Comment: @HansPassant So, why there exists `uv_is_active` and it can be used with an `uv_timer`? Wanting to start your car's engine twice without stopping it doesn't sound like a good decision. It serves the purpose of knowing if it's already started. I'm asking if there is an equivalent function that serves the purpose of knowing if it's already initialized. Quite simple a question, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested [here](http://pod.tst.eu/http://cvs.schmorp.de/libev/ev.pod#ASSOCIATING_CUSTOM_DATA_WITH_A_WATCH) (actually the documentation of `libev`, but the suggestion applies also to `libuv`):

> If you need more data and don't want to allocate memory separately and store a pointer to it in that data member, you can also "subclass" the watcher type and provide your own data:
>
> ```
> struct my_io {
>     ev_io io;
>     int otherfd;
>     void *somedata;
>     struct whatever *mostinteresting;
> };
>
> // ...
>
> struct my_io w;
> ev_io_init (&w.io, my_cb, fd, EV_READ);
> ```
>
> And since your callback will be called with a pointer to the watcher, you can cast it back to your own type:
>
> ```
> static void my_cb (struct ev_loop *loop, ev_io *w_, int revents) {
>     struct my_io *w = (struct my_io *)w_;
>     // ...
> }
> ```

Using a similar approach, we can define a new struct having a boolean parameter that indicates if it has been initialized or not.
Set it to false during the creation (a factory method could help here) and switch it to true once initialized.

Answer (score 2):

The comparison with `uv_is_closing` isn't really fitting. Closing can set a bit when you call it, which you can check for later. But when no function has even touched the handle yet, what do you expect to check for?

Nevertheless, there are workarounds:

#### Mark uninitialized handles

Explicitly zero your handles: `memset(&handle, 0x00, sizeof handle)`. To find out if the handle is uninitialized, check whether it's still all-bytes zero:

```
int is_all_zeroes(void *buf, size_t len) {
   for (unsigned char *p = buf; p < buf + len; p++) {
        if (*p != 0x00)
           return 0;
   }
   return 1;
}
```

This **assumes all-zero handles can't be valid objects**, which is a safe bet as any initialized libuv handle will contain non-null pointers and this is not likely to change in future.

#### Mark initialized handles

If we don't mark uninitialized objects, we will have to mark the initialized ones.

Keep a list of initialized handles. Add/remove entries as you initialize/close them.

---

Internally, libuv does already mark initialized handles. When a handle is initialized, it's added to a `uv_loop_t` specific `QUEUE`.

This **API isn't meant to be publicly** used however:

```
#define uv__handle_init(loop_, h, type_)                                      \
  do {                                                                        \
    (h)->loop = (loop_);                                                      \
    (h)->type = (type_);                                                      \
    (h)->flags = UV__HANDLE_REF;  /* Ref the loop when active. */             \
    QUEUE_INSERT_TAIL(&(loop_)->handle_queue, &(h)->handle_queue);            \
    uv__handle_platform_init(h);                                              \
  }                                                                           \
```

So you are better off keeping track of it on your own.

Comment: That queue could be the source of the behavior I'm observing. Initialize a handle twice means probably put it twice in the queue. I should look over the code of libuv to know what's happening there once I close the loop. Anyway, thank you for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

An initialized handle would have handle type different from `UV_UNKNOWN_HANDLE` so one could use the following approach:

```
if (uv_handle_get_type(handle) != UV_UNKNOWN_HANDLE) {
...
}
```

or, probably, even

```
if (uv_handle_type_name(uv_handle_get_type(handle)) != NULL) {
...
}
```

as that would check if the type of the handle in question is known to *libuv*.